# Pandas: grab positions in dataframe which indexes are listed in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose that I have 2 dataframes, with indexes populated so that elements in columns are unique, because in real data they are:

```
vals = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(10, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))
indexes = pd.DataFrame(np.argsort(np.random.randint(0,10,(10, 3)), axis=0)[:5], columns=list('ABC'))

>>> vals
    A   B   C
0  64  20  48
1  28  60  81
2   5  73  77
3  74  66  86
4  41  39  21
5  65  37  98
6  10  20  73
7   6  70   3
8  36  29  28
9  43  13  12

>>> indexes
   A  B  C
0  4  2  3
1  3  3  8
2  5  1  7
3  9  8  9
4  2  4  0
```

I would like to retain only those values in `vals` which indexes are listed in `indexes`. I don't care about row integrity or NAs, as I'll use the columns as Series later.

This is what I came up with:

```
vals_indexes = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(vals.shape[1]):
    vals_indexes = pd.concat([vals_indexes, vals.iloc[[e for e in indexes.iloc[:, i] if e in vals.index], i]], axis=1)

>>> vals_indexes
      A     B     C
0   NaN   NaN  48.0
1   NaN  60.0   NaN
2   5.0  73.0   NaN
3  74.0  66.0  86.0
4  41.0  39.0   NaN
5  65.0   NaN   NaN
7   NaN   NaN   3.0
8   NaN  29.0  28.0
9  43.0   NaN  12.0
```

Which is a bit ugly, but works for me. Question: is there a more effective way to do this?

Comment: why c=48 1st row is not nan ?
48 is not in indexes

Comment: But 0 is. I separated vals and indexes by one order.

Answer (score 2):

use `.loc` within a loop to replace non existing index with nan

```
for i in vals.columns:
    vals.loc[vals[i].isin(list(indexes[i].unique())),i]=np.nan

print(vals)
```

```
    A    B    C
0  NaN  2.0  NaN
1  NaN  5.0  NaN
2  2.0  3.0  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  6.0
5  9.0  NaN  NaN
6  NaN  NaN  4.0
7  NaN  7.0  NaN
8  2.0  NaN  NaN
9  NaN  NaN  NaN
```